# How to understand a patient's coma status in Buddhism

Tags: lay-buddhism, mind, pain

My friend was healthy and normal. There was a sudden bleeding in her brain due to an [AVM](http://www.strokeassociation.org/STROKEORG/AboutStroke/TypesofStroke/HemorrhagicBleeds/What-Is-an-Arteriovenous-Malformation-AVM_UCM_310099_Article.jsp#mainContent) and went through a serious brain surgery. Now around 3 weeks she is in a coma status. How can I understand this in Buddhism. Does she hear us? Can she feel what is going on? Is she in pain? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether a person can hear, see, smell, taste etc. while in a coma is probably a question for medical science.

From a Buddhist perspective, it can be seen as a case of senses being shut off as in when you are in deep sleep. Only [Bhavaanga Cittas(life continuum)](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/b_f/bhavanga_sota.htm) are present in deep(dreamless) sleep.

Alternatively, it could just be a case of the patient not being able to respond in anyway. Here's [such an instance](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/geoffrey-lean-i-was-in-a-coma-but-i-could-hear-every-word-415327.html).

The situation is probably different from patient to patient.

Comment: Thank you very much, specially for the encouraging example case given.